# Partition by weeknumber and next weeknumber

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to count for each customer how many times a specific product was purchased in the past. I want to highlight the purchases for the same product (where the second order date is close to the first order date)  with a `rn = 2`, so I can only count the rows with `rn = 1`

I created the following query and also included the current output. Its containing a `partition by` week number, to filter out purchases for the same product in the same week. It's working quite good,  but the behaviour is not exactly what I was hoping for.

```
create table  sandbox.hm_orders as 
select o.customer_id
,o.product_id
,o.order_date
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by o.customer_id, o.product_id,concat(EXTRACT(year FROM order_date),EXTRACT(week FROM order_date)) order by o.order_date asc) as rn
,concat(EXTRACT(year FROM o.order_date),'_',EXTRACT(week FROM o.order_date)) as weeknr
    from datamarts.orders o
    where o.label_id = 1
    and o.order_date > '2020-01-01'
    and o.payment_status = 'PAID'
```

**Current output:**

| customer_id | product_ID | order_date | rn | weeknr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4708818 | 128703 | 2020-05-11 20:19:25 | 1 | 2020_20 |
| 4708818 | 128703 | 2020-05-12 22:13:09 | 2 | 2020_20 |
| 4708818 | 128703 | 2020-06-06 21:45:04 | 1 | 2020_23 |
| 4708818 | 274578 | 2020-07-02 22:02:10 | 1 | 2020_27 |
| 4753958 | 137482 | 2021-03-14 18:13:04 | 1 | 2021_10 |
| 4753958 | 137482 | 2021-03-15 17:29:03 | 1 | 2021_11 |

As you can see in first two rows, the difference between the first the rows is 1 day and it will mark the second row with a `rowNumber 2`. For the last 2 rows, the difference between the orders is also 1 day. But since the weeknumbers are different, it will not give the second row a `rowNumber 2`.

Therefore I would like to find a way to also include the next weeknumber for the `partition by.` In this case, the order that have been done in 2021-11 needs a `row number 2`, and the week number 10 needs `row number 1`

**desired output**

| customer_id | product_ID | order_date | rn | weeknr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4708818 | 128703 | 2020-05-11 20:19:25 | 1 | 2020_20 |
| 4708818 | 128703 | 2020-05-12 22:13:09 | 2 | 2020_20 |
| 4708818 | 128703 | 2020-06-06 21:45:04 | 1 | 2020_23 |
| 4708818 | 274578 | 2020-07-02 22:02:10 | 1 | 2020_27 |
| 4753958 | 137482 | 2021-03-14 18:13:04 | 1 | 2021_10 |
| 4753958 | 137482 | 2021-03-15 17:29:03 | 2 | 2021_11 |

Comment: You have partitioned by `extract(week, ...)`. That extracts  ISO 8601 week-numbering. In ISO 8601 weeks always start on Monday and are always 7 days long.  Now the date 2021-03-14 is Sunday thus the last day of the week, so the next day 2021-03-15 the first day of the next week. The query result is correct. Apparently you want a different week numbering system. Your best approach will be to create a *Calander* table that contains the desired week number and select that value.

Comment: But with another week numbering system, it can also happen that two consecutive days have another week nummer. It’s no problem that the week Numbers not equals, but is that happens, the row Numbers must rn=2

Answer (score 0):

A bit complicated way is to calculate a ranking by summing over a calculated flag.
Then use the rank in the row_number.

> ```
> SELECT *
> , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by customer_id, product_id, rnk order by order_date asc) as rn
> , TO_CHAR(order_date, 'YYYY_WW') as weeknr
> FROM
> (
> SELECT *
> , SUM(flag) over (partition by customer_id, product_id order by order_date asc) as rnk
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT 
>     o.customer_id
>   , o.product_id
>   , o.order_date
>   , CASE WHEN 1 >= DATE_PART('day', o.order_date - LAG(o.order_date) over (partition by o.customer_id, o.product_id order by o.order_date asc))
>     THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag
>   FROM orders o
>   WHERE o.label_id = 1
>     AND o.order_date > '2020-01-01'
>     AND o.payment_status = 'PAID'
> ) q1
> ) q2
> ```

| customer_id | product_id | order_date | flag | rnk | rn | weeknr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4708818 | 128703 | 2020-05-11 20:19:25 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2020_19 |
| 4708818 | 128703 | 2020-05-12 22:13:09 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2020_19 |
| 4708818 | 128703 | 2020-06-06 21:45:04 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2020_23 |
| 4708818 | 274578 | 2020-07-02 22:02:10 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2020_27 |
| 4753958 | 137482 | 2021-03-14 18:13:04 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021_11 |
| 4753958 | 137482 | 2021-03-15 17:29:03 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2021_11 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=50368b0955efb3c61a28e92d2b5b1aa7)*

Comment: The last column (with week Numbers) was shown to illustrate. I can use another calculation for the week numbering system, but in that case it can also happen that two consecutive days have another week nummer. It’s no problem that the week Numbers not equals, but is that happens, the row Numbers must rn=2

Comment: Maybe the partition by week number is not the right way to go. Ideally I would like to give the second order a row Number 2 when the date date diff between the orders is smaller than 14 days, independent from the week numbers

Comment: @htermaten Something like the updated solution? Currently only 0 to 1 day diff.